# Can't call variable result inside string

Tags: javascript

So I have this piece of code:

```
    $(document).on('click','.download_now[data-inputid={{ $field['name'] }}-filemanager]',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var loc = document.getElementById('proofAttach-filemanager').value;
        document.location = "{{ url("+loc+") }}";

    });
```

However, I'm getting the following url:

http://localhost/+loc+

If I remove the plus sign I get /loc and if I insert document.getelementbyid right there I get the text instead of the result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Clearly, you have some preprocessor/template library that is handling thsoe `{{...}}` for you before the code is run (otherwise, you'd have a syntax error on the first line of the quoted code). That would almost certainly be happening on the **server**, before this goes out to the browser, so you can't use client-side information (`loc`) in those tags.

Comment: I don't think you can "template" the document.location field with an angular type template. You cannot just assign `document.location.href = url( loc )`; at least, when the url method is within your current scope :)

Comment: You guys are right. However, I wanted to handle it on javascript. I don't really need the template engine to extract the base url, I solved it by extracting the base URL via javascript:  `window.location.origin + "/" + loc`  Thanks!

Comment: @Rosenberg, rather than edit your original question, you should post the answer separately by answering it yourself.  That will help others with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved it**

By using javascript to extract the base URL:

```
        $(document).on('click','.download_now[data-inputid={{ $field['name'] }}-filemanager]',function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var loc = document.getElementById('proofAttach-filemanager').value;
        var base_url = window.location.origin;
        document.location = base_url + "/" + loc;

    });
```